# How to ensure that self outlives the return value without borrowing

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Suppose there was something like this:

```rust
trait B {}
struct BB {}
impl B for BB {}

struct A {}
impl A {
    // With this, A can be dropped before B
    // fn get_b(&mut self) -> Box<dyn B> {...}

    fn get_b<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Box<dyn B + 'a> {...}
    fn mut_a(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A {};
    let b = a.get_b();

    // These lines don't compile
    a.mut_a(); // A is borrowed. Is there any way to make this compile?

    // Does not compile and should not. b must be dropped before a
    drop(a);
    drop(b);
}
```

Is there any way to ensure that `a` outlives `b` (for `unsafe` code reasons) without keeping `a` borrowed?

EDIT: Both `a` and `b` must be mutable (if declared `mut`) and should remain moveable. The only thing it needs to ensure is that B is dropped before A.

Comment: For this example: you can enclose `let b= a.get_b();` with braces. Besides: The code is not compilable (missing semicolons, missing mut).

Comment: Ok, I added the `;`s and `mut`. Just adding braces is not good enough because it's a library and I can't rely on the user not to drop `a` first.

Comment: if `get_b` returned a `&'a dyn B` then you'd get the desired behavior

Comment: wait a minute, this already fails just fine ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a58ce0e10cb5b2e0af90db880c927c25)) or did I misunderstand and you *want* it to compile

Comment: It doesn't. The `B` needs to be owned. I also need to use `b` after mutating `a`.

Comment: It fails because the last two lines don't compile. The second last line should work, and the last one shouldn't.

Comment: `fn get_b<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Box<dyn B + 'a> {...}` means that `<dyn B + 'a>` implicitly  references `self`/'a' : Is this true? If not, you should replace/omit the lifetime. Otherwise you should try a solution with internal mutability and reference counted references.

Comment: Yes, but without it, `a` can be dropped before `b`.

Comment: do you have the `drop(_)` function or is it there as an example of normal Rust drop out of scope? because you can't check if user even calls `drop(_)` at compile time, not to say in  a valid order

Comment: I don't care how the user drops it, just that `a` not dropped before `b`. For example, the user shouldn't be able to return `b` and have `a` dropped at the end of the function.

Comment: You might be able to use a lifetime parameter on `A` or `B` (probably with [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html)). You could also do it dynamically using `Rc` (probably with [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html)).

Comment: Something involving multiple fields and only borrowing one of them should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you give `A` two fields, say `lifetime` and `data`, you can have `get_b` take shared references to `lifetime` and have `mut_a` take a mutable reference to `data`:

```rust
trait B {}
struct BB {}
impl B for BB {}

struct A {
    pub lifetime: ALifetime,
    pub data: AData,
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    private: (), // prevent destructuring
}
struct ALifetime {}
struct AData {}
impl A {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { lifetime: ALifetime {}, data: AData {}, private: () }
    }
}
impl ALifetime {
    fn get_b<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn B + 'a> { Box::new(BB{}) }
}
impl AData {
    fn mut_a(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    let b = a.lifetime.get_b();
    a.data.mut_a(); // Only `a.data` is borrowed here.
    // drop(b);
    drop(a); // Not allowed. b must be dropped before a
}
```

<sup>Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ccd1a25cacd21d4364f2f3add1499015</sup>

Comment: You can still cause UB in safe code by calling `drop(a.data)`.

Comment: @me' Would making `A` `impl Drop` instead of `AData` fix that?

Comment: You would still be able to `mem::swap` `AData` to another `A` and drop that.